# Dynamic array that halfs the biggest element and creates a new one c++

Tags: c++, arrays, input, dynamic, output

so the task is like that:
The user has to type the number of the elements in the array, they have to be >3 and <1024, the elemets in the array have to %2==0, so the user types the element, then the user has to type another number, so for example if the array is 2 4 6 8 2 and the user **types 1**, the program has to find the biggest number in the array, half it and the program should should the new array like that [2 4 6 4 4 2]
BUT if the user has typed 3 or another number, the program should find the biggest num, half it, then find again the biggest num, half it and its like that (it does that the num that the user has typer /the user has typed 3->it finds the biggest num, halfs, finds the new biggest one, halfs it, finds the new biggest one, half it). Also if the nums in the array are only 2 2 2 2 the program should cout "Try again"

I have done this so far, please help me, I am new to these things and I need help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{

  int i,n, numa, half;

  int * p;

  cout << "How many numbers would you like to type? ";

  cin >> i;

  p= new (nothrow) int[i];

  if(i<4 || i>1024)
{

      cout<<"Invalid input!";

      return 1;

  }

  if (p == nullptr)

    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";

  else

  {

    for (n=0; n<i; n++)

    {

      cout << "Enter number: ";

      cin >> p[n];

    }

    cout<<"A<num>, enter a number: "; //thats how many times u have to find the biggest num and half it

    cin>>numa;

    for(i = 1; i < n; ++i)

    {

       if(p[0] < p[i])

           p[0]=p[i];
    }

    cout<<p[0]<<endl;

    half=p[0]/2;

    cout<<half<<endl;
  }


  delete[] p;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi, to allow others to better read your code, please use [Markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Unrelated: `p= new (nothrow) int[i];` is something you should only do when you have a very good reason. If the allocation of the array fails, there is no memory for example, you want the program to throw an exception. This is the sort of exceptional event exceptions were made for.

Comment: the task is to use dynamic array :)

Comment: Note: at a time, you reverse the roles of `i` and `n`. This makes the programme more difficult to read. Better is to use meaningful names as `size`.

Comment: What to do if you halve a number two or more times such that it become an odd integer? E.g. 6/2 = 3, then 3/2 = 1.5, ..

Answer (score 1):

In C++ dynamic "arrays" will be handled by the [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You may read there for more details.

Your question/task/requirements are not so clear and somehow hard to understand. Anyway, from what I understood, I have slpit the overall task into smaller tasks and created some demo for you.

If it is not what you expected, then please give me a better description and I will modify it.

Please see one of the many possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

constexpr size_t MinNumberElementsInVector = 4U;
constexpr size_t MaxNumberElementsInVector = 1024U;

size_t getNumberOfVectorElements() {
    // inform user, what to do
    size_t result{ 0U };

    do {
        std::cout << "\nPlease enter, how many numbers the test array should have.\n"
            "The given number must be >=" << MinNumberElementsInVector << "and <="
            << MaxNumberElementsInVector << ".\nPlease enter: ";

        // Get value from user and check range
        if (!((std::cin >> result) && (result >= MinNumberElementsInVector) && (result <= MaxNumberElementsInVector))) {
            // Error in input. Reset result to 0 and show error message
            result = 0U;
            std::cout << "\n\nError during input. Try Again.\n\n";
        }
    } while (0 == result);
    return result;
}
size_t getNumberOfActions() {
    // inform user, what to do
    size_t result{ 0U };

    do {
        std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter, how many times the half operation should be done.\n"
            "The given number must be > 0.\nPlease enter: ";

        // Get value from user and check range
        if (!((std::cin >> result) && (result > 0))) {
            // Error in input. Reset result to 0 and show error message
            result = 0U;
            std::cout << "\n\nError during input. Try Again.\n\n";
        }
    } while (0 == result);
    return result;
}

std::vector<int> getVectorWithEvenNumbers(size_t numberOfElements) {

    // Limit the number of elements to the correct range
    numberOfElements = std::clamp(numberOfElements, MinNumberElementsInVector, MaxNumberElementsInVector);

    // Resulting vector. Reserve space for "numberOfElements" numbers
    std::vector<int> result(numberOfElements);

    // Get numbers from user
    for (bool allEven = false; !allEven; ) {

        // Give info for user
        std::cout << "\n\nPlease enter " << numberOfElements << " even numbers:\n";

        // Read all values from user
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfElements, result.begin());

        // Check, if all values are even

        allEven = std::all_of(result.begin(), result.end(), [](const int i) {return (i % 2) == 0; });

        // Error message, in case of odd values
        if (!allEven) std::cout << "\n\nError during input. Try Again.\n\n";
    }
    return result;
}

void halfMaxValues(std::vector<int>& values) {
    // Search max value
    std::vector<int>::iterator max = std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end());
    if ((max != values.end()) && ((*max > 2) || (*max < -2))) {
        int m = *max;
        // Half all found max values, if even
        std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [&m](int& i) {if ((i % 2 == 0) && (i == m)) {i /= 2;}});
    }
}

// Show contents of vector on screen
inline void displayVector(std::vector<int> values) {
    std::cout << "\nResult:\n";
    std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {

    // Get number of elements for our vector
    size_t numberOfVectorElements{ getNumberOfVectorElements() };

    // Get the elements and put them into the vector
    std::vector<int> values{ getVectorWithEvenNumbers(numberOfVectorElements) };

    // How many times should we perfom the action
    size_t numberOfActions{ getNumberOfActions() };

    while (numberOfActions-- && !std::all_of(values.begin(), values.end(), [](int i) {return (i == 2) || (i == -2) || (i % 2 == 1); })) {
        halfMaxValues(values);
        displayVector(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but as I said we havent studied vectors and algorithms so we cant use them

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example using `std::vector` instead of a raw array of ints:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void read_items(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    int i = 0;
    int nitems = v.size();
    while( i < nitems ) {
        std::cout << "Enter number: ";
        std::cin >> v[i];
        if (v[i] < 2) {
            std::cout << "Error: number has to be larger or equal to 2!\n";
        }
        else if (v[i] % 2 != 0) {
            std::cout << "Error: enter even numbers only!\n";
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
void print_vector(const std::vector<int> &v) {
    std::cout << "v: ";
    for (auto &item : v ) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main ()
{

    std::cout << "How many numbers would you like to type? ";
    int nitems;
    std::cin >> nitems;

    if(nitems<4 || nitems>1024) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<int> v(nitems);

    read_items(v);
    print_vector(v);

    // how many times u have to find the biggest num and half it
    std::cout << "A<num>, enter a number: ";
    int numa;
    std::cin >> numa;
    for (int k = 0; k < numa; k++) {
        int max = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
        for(int  j = 1; j < nitems; j++) {
            if(v[j] == max)
                v[j] /= 2;
        }
        print_vector(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks but we havent studied vectors so we cant use them